# tidesdk development with macosx 10.6.8 (snow leopard)

Tags: tidesdk

I am attempting to do an R&D desktop app project and I would like to use TideSDK as my framework. Unfortunately it would seem that my mac is running OSX 10.6.8 and from what I was able to determine, TideSDK (at least the developer) will only work for OSX 10.7+. Does anyone know if it it is just the developer app that will not work with OSX 10.6.8 or if all of the TideSDK will not work?

I'd really like to use this framework over AIR if that's possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TideSDK does in fact work on OSX 10.6. As long as you're relatively comfortable using the command line, you can build an application without Developer. For guidance packaging an application with the command line, look here: https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/Packaging-TideSDK-apps

Answer (score 0):

TideSDK is not actively supported for OSX 10.6 as you can see from here: https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues/94

I also had errors related to network calls using 10.6, so i guess it's not a good option to use TideSDK with OSX less than 10.7.